# Is there a way to go up a certain number of directories depending on the current location?

Tags: html, css, jekyll

I'm trying to implement Jekyll to my site and I'm having a hard time setting paths for my images since I don't know how to allot for the different paths since the permalink to each post is one folder deeper than the homepage. How can I make it so that my images both show in the homepage and in their individual pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use absolute paths for your images:

```
<img src="/image_folder/image.jpg" />
```

This way it doesn't matter where in the hierarchy the HTML file is as the image always is permanent in relation to the root folder.